# Hook property binding

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I am trying to hook an `ImageUrl` property to `MvxImageView`, to implement my own image caching service.

I have tried using a `PropertyConverter` that gets the value, but I don't receive a response.

Then, I tried my own implementation for `IMvxImageHelper`, but I get an unusual behaviour because I using a list with images, all images containers get the same picture and when I swipe the list, the picture changes in all `MvxImageView` widgets.

This implementation is in a Setup file in `CreateApp` method using a `RegisterSingleton`.

What is the correct way to hook into the process of caching images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the entire download and caching chain then the easiest interface to provide is `IMvxImageHelper<Bitmap>` - it's expected that this is registered as `Mvx.RegisterType` - so that each image view will get a new helper object.

If you want to replace just parts of the download and caching, then you can instead provide implementations of:

```
        IMvxHttpFileDownloader
        IMvxImageCache<Bitmap>
        IMvxLocalFileImageLoader<Bitmap>
```

There's no documentation available for these - but these api's are very small and the source code is available as a reference.

---

> Then, I tried my own implementation for IMvxImageHelper, but I get an unusual behaviour because I using a list with images, all images containers get the same picture and when I swipe the list, the picture changes in all MvxImageView widgets.

I would **guess** you had a bug in your image helper implementation or in it's registration with IOC.

---

One other alternative you can consider is implementing your own custom `ImageView` class with its own `ImageUrl` property - you don't have to use `MvxImageView`

Comment: The unusual behavior for MvxImageHelper it's for I use RegisterSingleton instead of RegisterType and I use the same object for all MvxImageView. Thanks Stuart one more time!